# reconstructing lost code (InArray) - cont

Tags: delphi

I am missing a unit from some code that another developer worked on.

I have been able to decipher some, and experts here have helped me with others,

I need a boolean function called InArray.

I know it takes a TIntArray and integer and returns a boolean of whether or not the integer exists in the TIntArray

```
TIntArray = array of Integer;


function InArray (A: TIntArray; n: Integer): Boolean;
begin
 // result:=
end;
```

I am not sure how the rest of it is completed.

any help would be appreciated.

thanx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely, the function tests if `n` belongs to the array:

```
function InArray(A: TIntArray; n: Integer): boolean;
var
  i: integer;
begin
  result := false;
  for i := low(A) to high(A) do
    if A[i] = n then
      Exit(true);
end;
```

If you are using an old version of Delphi (<2009), you have to do

```
function InArray(A: TIntArray; n: Integer): boolean;
var
  i: integer;
begin
  result := false;
  for i := low(A) to high(A) do
    if A[i] = n then
    begin
      result := true;
      break;
    end;
end;
```

instead.

Comment: Why assign to Result twice? I do yearn for the return statement of C derived languages.

Comment: Matter of taste. To me I think my version is a tiny, tiny bit easier to read. (Doesn't `Exit(retVal)` count?)

Comment: You still assign twice. As a mathematician of pure tastes, that grates mildly. Modern exit is better. But it's still a bloody var parameter rather than pass by value from func to caller as in all other languages. Vent vent. Rant rant.

Comment: I tend to initialize results in the first line too, although I know how unnecessary it is. Boolean results are automatically false until you make it true.

Comment: @Jerry Automatically False? That's your convention right?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Couldn't resist: as a developer of pure tastes any early Exit outside of "contract assertions" grates and not just mildly... :-D ... but lets keep the lid on this Pandorra's box of religious exit discussions.

Comment: @Marjan Leaving the function as soon as the result is known can be thought of in the same light as contract assertions. I expect you don't mind short circuit boolean evaluation....

Comment: @David, I don't understand your first comment. How do you suggest to initialize the Result in this case? Are you relying on the Result being initialized to True?

Comment: @kobik: Have a look at David's deleted answer (I think you can do that, but I'm not sure).

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand, I don't have enough rep.

Comment: @kobik: OK, sorry. Well, @David iterates and on a match he does `Exit(True)` and the last line of his function is `result := false`.

Comment: @kobik Now you can see it

Comment: @David, Andreas, Thanks. I would call it an Optimistic vs. Pessimistic  approach. I use the later approach usually.

Comment: @kobik Hmm. I'm not sure pessimism should come into programming.  ;-)

Comment: @David, You might say I worry too much, and trust no one. :)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Multiple paths out of a method other than the contract assertions add to the cognitive burden for reading that method. And code is read far more often than written... The effect of an "early exit" can often be achieved in other ways than using an `exit`. I don't object to short circuit boolean evaluation. To me that is on the same level as a `break` out of a loop: toward the end of the statement it pertains to but no further than the end of that statement. I tend to avoid `continue` as it moves back up instead of down...

Comment: @MarjanVenema In this case we have a pure function that mutates no state, has no side effects. Would you really prefer to run the entire loop even if you find the target value on the first iteration?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Where did I say that I object to break? I simply prefer the "always initialize" and "don't early exit" approach.

Comment: @MarjanVenema There's really no difference between exit, break and continue

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: there is. Exit has a farther reaching scope than break or continue as Exit leaves the method, whereas break and continue only "exit" the statement they pertain to.

Comment: @Marjan But your break could well jump you pass an assignment to Result. So I honestly don't see the difference. To me I actually find a greater impedence with break in this scenario. We have a **pure** function whose sole job is to set Result. I just wish I could write return True instead of Pascal's lame exit.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Yes it could. Much of this is preference and depends on your mileage. In this _particular_ function there indeed is hardly any difference between break and exit. My comments stem more from being bitten by __multiple__ exit statements in (longer) methods that need to do (a lot) more to determine their result.

Comment: @Marjan I agree for that longer complex routines, especially with side effects then breaks and exits are a nightmare. FWiW, in my code I would write TArray.Contains<Integer>(arr, value) and use lovely generics!!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Yeah, don't you just love them :-)

Comment: @JohnnyHolmes I think you should accept Andreas's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
function InArray (A: TIntArray; n: Integer): Boolean; 
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to high(A) do
    if A[i]=n then
    begin
      Result := True;
      exit;
    end;
  Result := False;
end;
```

Comment: Yeah, said the same thing ages ago! :)